# Keep language option from previous page

Tags: heroku, django-settings

I did multi-linguistic webpages with two language buttons on each page. It should work in the way when people click Next and their language option of the previous page maintains on the next page. It works like this on my local host, but when deploying it on Heroku the language option always turns back to the default language when clicking Next. I wonder if this problem is because something is missed when Heroku fetches my codes from git remote repository?

I also host the webpage on Linux server. Like on my local host, the problem doesn't happen on Linux server. I'm pretty sure the problem is with the git repository and/or Heroku. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide some code for a minimal, workable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is gone when I recently upload app to Heroku. When a language button is toggled, the language choice is carried to next page on Heroku. I tried to figure out how the problem is solved. There are two possible reasons: One is Heroku platform is somehow updated, the other could be some changes in my oTree codes. I attach some changes I made in my codes, in case someone got the same problem. Note that otree must be <5 for now, because otree 5.0 now is not compatible with Django and to develop multi-linguistic page, Django is very necessary.

Codes in requirements.txt:

```
    -r requirements_base.txt
    psycopg>=2.5.1
    otree==3.0.9
```

Codes in requirements_base.txt:

```
    numpy>=1.16.2
    scipy>=1.1.0
```